# Visual Studio Add-in. How to disable menu item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, add-in, extensibility

I am writing a C# addin for VS 2012.
I want to add a menu item to the tools menu. I want this menu item to be disabled when Studio starts and became enable or disabled depending on if solution/project is loaded or not.

I used to be able to do this by processing QueryStatus method and setting (or not setting ) the 
status to vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled when appropriate.
The problem is that QueryStatus for some reason is not called anymore until i click the menu "Tools" and therefore i cannot disable my menu item.
Can anybody help?

I connect to my addin by processing OnConnection

```
if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
{
........
}
```

and my addin xml looks like

```
<LoadBehavior>1</LoadBehavior>
<CommandPreload>1</CommandPreload>
<CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar problem with `UISetup`: [Social.MSDN: Visual Studio no longer sends ext_cm_UISetup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53eed1cf-99c6-46d3-a17d-ea1008ba14a9/visual-studio-no-longer-sends-extcmuisetup)

> Notice that ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup is fired only once in the whole life of an add-in on the computer, that is, it is not fired each time that the add-in is loaded. The flag ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup is intended to create permanent user interface only once and forever.

While your Add-In is not loaded, you can't manage your menu items throuhg `QueryStatus`.

About `UISetup` on [MZ-Tools HOWTO: Controlling the state of command in a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/mz2007025.aspx)

> For this kind of add-ins with a permanent user interface, since you
>   will want the same state for a command independently of whether the
>   add-in is loaded or not, you must ensure that the logic of your
>   ContextUIGUIDs / vsCommandDisabledFlagsValue parameters in the AddNamedCommand call and the logic of your 
>   QueryStatus method are the same.

So I think you should use non permanent buttons:

```
if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_AfterStartup || connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)
{
  ...
}
```

or you can set the `UIContext` properly. Query status shouldn't be called while your Add-In is not loaded, It may be corrected.

If you create non permanent buttons, they will be shown with correct state while your Add-in loaded, then you should delete them. I used this solution before.

This solution can lead you to left several garbage buttons in special cases after Add-In uninstall. I can't find working solution to clean them always. But they can be deleted manually for good.

Answer (score 0):

QueryStatus is not called until the menu item is about to be shown, but this shouldn't be a problem as the user can't see that your menu item is disabled until it is shown. If you are worried that the user might use a hot key to execute the command, then just check if the command can be used in your Execute method as well.